# Rings having the same characters but not isomorphic.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, self-learning

I want to show that these two rings have the same characters but they are not isomorphic for $\nu>2$ Thank you for helping.

> $$H=k+kt^{4\nu}(1+t)+kt^{6\nu}(1+t)+kt^{7\nu}(1+t)+k[[t]]t^{8\nu}$$
>   $$H^\prime=k+kt^{4\nu}(1+t+t^2)+kt^{6\nu}(1+t+t^2)+kt^{7\nu}(1+t+t^2)+k[[t]]t^{8\nu}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't even understand the notation (I'm sure it's standard). Is $k$ a field and does $+$ denote direct sum?

Comment: I understand that $k[[t]]$ is probably the ring of formal power series but what is $k[[t]]t^{8 \nu}$?

Comment: In fact, This ring is called as an Arf ring @user26857